# Reformat JSON in JOLT

Tags: json, mapping, transformation, jolt

I want to restructure json. I want an array inside a object.

Left side is the desired ouput. Right side is the current output.

[image]

I have tried the below solution but it created an extra "{,}' which I didn't wanted. Any idea on what changes I can make to my JOLT spec to get the above right side output?

[image]

After trying the above solution I got the below-

[image]

I don't want the yellow highlighted part.

My JSON Input-

```json
{
  "PURCHASE_ORDER_DISPATCH": {
    "MsgData": {
      "Transaction": {
        "PO_POD_HDR_EVW1": {
          "WG_ADDR_SEQ_NUM": 1,
          "WG_PO_CNTCT_EMAIL": "PeggyMeincke@westfieldgrp.com",
          "WG_REQUESTOR_EMAIL": "ZacharyEngels@westfieldgrp.com",
          "WG_REQ_FIRST_NAME": "Zachary",
          "WG_REQ_LAST_NAME": "Engels",
          "WG_DELIVER_TO": "ZacharyEngels@westfieldgrp.com",
          "BUSINESS_UNIT": "OFIC",
          "PO_ID": 25052,
          "VENDOR_SETID": "WCOS",
          "VENDOR_ID": 35958,
          "VNDR_LOC": 1,
          "PO_POD_LN_EVW1": {
            "WG_REQ_ID": 25694,
            "WG_CATEGORY_CD": "FSSUP",
            "WG_ITEM_TYPE": 0,
            "WG_ACCOUNT": 641100,
            "WG_DEPT_ID": 30400,
            "WG_PRODUCT": "",
            "BUSINESS_UNIT": "OFIC",
            "PO_ID": 25052,
            "WG_ASSET_GROUP": "",
            "WG_CAPITALIZE": "NO",
            "WG_PROFILE_ID": "",
            "WG_SPLIT_TYPE": 1,
            "WG_ASSET_LOC": "HOME",
            "WG_PROJECT": "",
            "VENDOR_SETID": "WCOS",
            "VENDOR_ID": 35958,
            "VNDR_LOC": 1,
            "LINE_NBR": 1,
            "INV_ITEM_ID": "",
            "DESCR254_MIXED": "147-1518156-3620845,1GreenMountainCoffeeRoastersCaramelVanillaCreamKeurigSingle-ServeK-CupPods,LightRoastCoffee,32Count",
            "UNIT_OF_MEASURE": "EA",
            "ITM_ID_VNDR": "B0798CX2Q9",
            "INV_ITEM_WEIGHT": 0,
            "INV_ITEM_HEIGHT": 0,
            "INV_ITEM_VOLUME": 0,
            "INV_ITEM_LENGTH": 0,
            "INV_ITEM_WIDTH": 0,
            "VNDR_CATALOG_ID": "",
            "MFG_ID": "",
            "MFG_ITM_ID": 5000196305,
            "CNTRCT_ID": "",
            "VERSION_NBR": 0,
            "CNTRCT_LINE_NBR": 0,
            "CAT_LINE_NBR": 0,
            "RELEASE_NBR": 0,
            "CANCEL_STATUS": "A",
            "UPN_ID": "",
            "PO_POD_SHP_EVW1": {
              "WG_SHIP_ADDR_TYPE": 0,
              "WG_CUST_ADDR_CODE": "OFIC",
              "BUSINESS_UNIT": "OFIC",
              "PO_ID": 25052,
              "VENDOR_SETID": "WCOS",
              "VENDOR_ID": 35958,
              "VNDR_LOC": 1,
              "LINE_NBR": 1,
              "SCHED_NBR": 1,
              "DUE_DT": "2020-01-29",
              "SHIPTO_ID": "OFIC",
              "DESCR_SHIPTO": "OHIOFARMERSINSURANCECOMPANY",
              "ADDRESS1_SHIPTO": "OHIOFARMERSINSURANCECOMPANY",
              "ADDRESS2_SHIPTO": "1PARKCIRCLE",
              "ADDRESS3_SHIPTO": "POBOX5001",
              "ADDRESS4_SHIPTO": "",
              "CITY_SHIPTO": "WESTFIELDCENTER",
              "STATE_SHIPTO": "OH",
              "POSTAL_SHIPTO": "44251-5001",
              "COUNTRY_SHIPTO": "USA",
              "PRICE_PO": 14.99,
              "FREIGHT_TERMS": "FOBDEST",
              "QTY_PO": 1,
              "SHIP_TYPE_ID": "BEST_WAY",
              "CANCEL_STATUS": "A",
              "ATTN_TO": "",
              "STD_ID_NUM_SHIPTO": ""
            },
            "PSCAMA": {
              "AUDIT_ACTN": "A"
            }
          },
          "PSCAMA": {
            "AUDIT_ACTN": "A"
          }
        },
        "PSCAMA": {
          "LANGUAGE_CD": "ENG",
          "AUDIT_ACTN": "A",
          "BASE_LANGUAGE_CD": "ENG",
          "MSG_SEQ_FLG": "",
          "PROCESS_INSTANCE": 1199010,
          "PUBLISH_RULE_ID": "WG_MAIN_RULE",
          "MSGNODENAME": ""
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

JOLT SPEC-

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": {
              "requestorDetails": "=concat(@(1,WG_REQ_FIRST_NAME),' ',@(1,WG_REQ_LAST_NAME))"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "#integrationTrackingNumber": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityHeader.integrationTrackingNumber",
      "#referenceCodeForEntity": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityHeader.referenceCodeForEntity",
      "#additionalInfo": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityHeader.additionalInfo",
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": {
              "PO_ID": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.externalId",
              "#APPROVED": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.status",
              "PO_AMT_TTL": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.grossTotalAmount",
              "#test.test\\@test.com": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.checkoutBuyer.userEmailId",
              "requestorDetails": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.requesterDetails",
              "FREIGHT_TERMS": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.deliveryTermCode",
              "WG_REQUESTOR_EMAIL": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.requesterDetails.userEmailId",
              "WG_DELIVER_TO": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.deliveryTo.userEmailId",
              "#OFIC": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.company.companyCode",
              "BUSINESS_UNIT": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.businessUnit.buCode",
              "PYMNT_TERMS_CD": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.paymentTermId",
              "#1": [
                "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.costingSplitLevel",
                "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.costingSplitType"
              ],
              "WG_ADDR_SEQ_NUM": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.supplierAddress.addressERPID",
              "CURRENCY_CD": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.supplierCurrencyCode",
              "@WG_ADDR_SEQ_NUM": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.supplierAddressERPID",
              "VENDOR_ID": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.supplierERPID",
              "WG_PO_CNTCT_EMAIL": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.suppPOContactEmail",
              "#2": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.supplierPOContactType",
              "WG_REQ_FIRST_NAME": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.requesterDetails.userFirstName",
              "WG_REQ_LAST_NAME": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.requesterDetails.userLastName",
              "@CURRENCY_CD": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.currency",
              "@WG_DELIVER_TO": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.deliverToUser.userEmailId",
              "*": {
                "WG_REQ_ID": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.poDescription",
                "#STANDARD": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.poType",
                "LINE_NBR": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.lineNumber",
                "WG_CATEGORY_CD": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.categoryCode",
                "WG_ITEM_TYPE": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.itemType",
                "MFG_ITM_ID": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.manufacturerPartID",
                "ITM_ID_VNDR": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.supplierPartID",
                "WG_ACCOUNT": {
                  "@": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[0].value",
                  "#name4": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[0].id",
                  "#AUTO_COMPLETE": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[0].type",
                  "#GL_ACCOUNT": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[0].name"
                },
                "WG_DEPT_ID": {
                  "@": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[1].value",
                  "#name3": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[1].id",
                  "#AUTO_COMPLETE": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[1].type",
                  "#Westfield Department": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[1].name"
                },
                "WG_PRODUCT": {
                  "@": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[2].value",
                  "#name6": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[2].id",
                  "#AUTO_COMPLETE": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[2].type",
                  "#Product/Parcel": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[2].name"
                },
                "WG_PROJECT": {
                  "@": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[3].value",
                  "#name5": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[3].id",
                  "#AUTO_COMPLETE": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[3].type",
                  "#Project Code": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[3].name"
                },
                "WG_ASSET_GROUP": {
                  "@": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[4].value",
                  "#name10": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[4].id",
                  "#AUTO_COMPLETE": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[4].type",
                  "#Asset Group": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[4].name"
                },
                "WG_CAPITALIZE": {
                  "@": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[5].value",
                  "#name9": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[5].id",
                  "#AUTO_COMPLETE": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[5].type",
                  "#Capitalize": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[5].name"
                },
                "WG_PROFILE_ID": {
                  "@": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[6].value",
                  "#name9": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[6].id",
                  "#AUTO_COMPLETE": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[6].type",
                  "#Profile Id": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[6].name"
                },
                "WG_ASSET_LOC": {
                  "@": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[7].value",
                  "#name2": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[7].id",
                  "#AUTO_COMPLETE": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[7].type",
                  "#Business Unit": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[7].name"
                },
                "BUSINESS_UNIT": {
                  "@": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[8].value",
                  "#name7": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[8].id",
                  "#AUTO_COMPLETE": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[8].type",
                  "#GL_ACCOUNT": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[8].name"
                },
                "*": {
                  "@WG_SHIP_ADDR_TYPE": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddressType",
                  "WG_SHIP_ADDR_TYPE": {
                    "2": {
                      "@(2,DESCR_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.addressName",
                      "@(2,ADDRESS1_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.addressLine1",
                      "@(2,ADDRESS2_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.addressLine2",
                      "@(2,ADDRESS3_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.addressLine3",
                      "@(2,ADDRESS4_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.addressLine4",
                      "@(2,CITY_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.city",
                      "@(2,POSTAL_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.zip",
                      "@(2,STATE_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.state",
                      "@(2,COUNTRY_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.country"
                    }
                  },
                  "WG_CUST_ADDR_CODE": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.addressCode",
                  "FREIGHT_TERMS": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.deliveryTermCode",
                  "SHIPTO_ID": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.locationCode.location.locationCode",
                  "DUE_DT": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.deliverOn",
                  "@DUE_DT": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.deliveryOn",
                  "PRICE_PO": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.marketPrice",
                  "QTY_PO": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.itemQuantity",
                  "@WG_CUST_ADDR_CODE": {
                    "2": {
                      "@(2,DESCR_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddress.addressName",
                      "@(2,ADDRESS1_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddress.addressLine1",
                      "@(2,ADDRESS2_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddress.addressLine2",
                      "@(2,ADDRESS3_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddress.addressLine3",
                      "@(2,ADDRESS4_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddress.addressLine4",
                      "@(2,CITY_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddress.city",
                      "@(2,POSTAL_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddress.zip",
                      "@(2,STATE_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddress.state",
                      "@(2,COUNTRY_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddress.country"
                    }
                  },
                  "#1": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.costingSplitType"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": {
              "*": {
                "*": {
                  "product": "=divide(1,@(1,itemQuantity))",
                  "itemTotalAmount": "=divide(@(1,marketPrice),@(1,product))",
                  "distributedAmount": "=divide(@(1,marketPrice),@(1,product))"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "integrationEntityHeader": "&2.&1.&",
          "integrationEntityDetails": {
            "*": {
              "externalId": "&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
              "status": "&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
              "poHeader": {
                "poDescription": "&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                "poType": "&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                "grossTotalAmount": "&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                "checkoutBuyer": {
                  "userEmailId": "&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&"
                },
                "requesterDetails": "&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                "userEmailId": "&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                "deliveryTo": {
                  "userEmailId": "&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&"
                },
                "deliveryTermCode": "&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                "shipToAddressType": "&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                "shipToAddress": "&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                "company": "&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                "businessUnit": "&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                "locationCode": "&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                "deliverOn": "&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                "paymentTermId": "&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                "costingSplitLevel": "&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                "costingSplitType": "&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                "supplierAddress": "&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                "supplierAddressERPID": "&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                "supplierCurrencyCode": "&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                "supplierERPID": "&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                "suppPOContactEmail": "&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                "supplierPOContactType": "&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&"
              },
              "items": {
                "item": {
                  "lineNumber": "&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                  "requesterDetails": "&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                  "categoryCode": "&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                  "currency": "&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                  "deliverToUser": {
                    "userEmailId": "&7.&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&"
                  },
                  "deliveryOn": "&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                  "itemTotalAmount": "&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                  "itemType": "&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                  "manufacturerPartID": "&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                  "marketPrice": "&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                  "itemQuantity": "&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                  "shipToAddressCode": "&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                  "shipToAddressType": "&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                  "costingSplitType": "&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                  "supplierPartID": "&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                  "validCombinations": {
                    "itemDetails": {
                      "@(2,distributedAmount)": "&8.&7.&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.distributedAmount",
                      "validRules": {
                        "field": {
                          "*": {
                            "id": "&11.&10.&9.&8.&7.&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.[&1].&",
                            "type": "&11.&10.&9.&8.&7.&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.[&1].&",
                            "name": "&11.&10.&9.&8.&7.&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.[&1].&",
                            "value": "&11.&10.&9.&8.&7.&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.[&1].&"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": {
              "status": "ONE",
              "poHeader": {
                "*": "ONE",
                "checkoutBuyer": {
                  "userEmailId": "ONE"
                },
                "company": {
                  "*": "ONE"
                }
              },
              "items": {
                "item": {
                  "costingSplitType": "ONE",
                  "validCombinations": {
                    "itemDetails": {
                      "validRules": {
                        "field": {
                          "id": "ONE",
                          "type": "ONE",
                          "name": "ONE",
                          "value": "ONE"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": {
              "poHeader": {
                "costingSplitLevel": "=toInteger",
                "costingSplitType": "=toInteger",
                "supplierPOContactType": "=toInteger"
              },
              "items": {
                "item": {
                  "costingSplitType": "=toInteger"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an extra **shift** transformation to the end containing a `#` wildcard at the right-hand-side such as

```json
{
  "operation": "shift",
  "spec": {
    "*": {
      "*": {
        "*": "&2.&1[#2].&"
      }
    }
  }
}
```